# Cannot install anything through Terminal - apt-get -f install

Tags: installation, apt, command-line

I get this when ever i try and install anything with th Terminal:

```
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.6.12-z) but 2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa3~precise is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.6.12-z) but 2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa3~precise is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I added myself to the root group in the grub recovery mode. Then did `sudo apt-get -f install` and got this:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa3~precise_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Two things: have you actually tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` like it suggests, and did you recently add a PPA to try and get GIMP 2.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, from what I can tell, your problem is that you've added a PPA to try and upgrade to the latest version of GIMP, and it hasn't worked out. I think the best option for now is to remove the PPA so you can get back your ability to install software.

Open Update Manager and hit `Settings`. This will bring you to the Software Sources manager, which you can read more about [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). Go to the "Other Software" tab and untick any PPA's you added related to GIMP.

Then open a terminal, and type these commands one at a time (you may have to run the third command before `sudo apt-get remove gimp` if it fails):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove gimp
sudo apt-get -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

GIMP will be uninstalled, but it should get your system working again. You should also be able to reinstall the default version of GIMP from the repositories.

Comment: I would just like to point out that Gimp 2.8 is very easy to build from source. http://www.gregorystrike.com/2012/05/03/how-to-build-gimp-2-8-from-source-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: @gecko Thanks, I was hoping that someone would post a guide like that as I've been meaning to check out 2.8 for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <yourapp>
```

Comment: `build-dep` is used to install build dependencies. Could you elaborate why and how this would solve the OP's problem?

Comment: Because the problem is about dependencies and probably the tree es corrupt or have any error, in my case sudo apt-get -f install did no solve the problem.

Comment: This solved a similar problem here. The cause? Some packages that were installed with dpkg -i.