# Need Help to fix hmtl.sty not found error

Tags: software-installation

I installed texlive 2012 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit machine following the instructions given in the following web

[How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)

After, a successful installation( I think), I got the following error when I do a pdflatex to compile a give tex file

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

restricted \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode

(./user_guide.tex

LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>

Babel and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo aded.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls

Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))

! LaTeX Error: File `html.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

so would you help me in getting a solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found more answers then questions, so I will give an answer. 
install:

```
sudo apt-get install latex2html
```

then it should work :)
(it did on my system)