# How to deal with configuration style warnings occuring from TexLive 2012 installation?

Tags: configuration, ppa, fonts, latex, backport

I followed the advice of [izx on how to install TexLive 2012 using the texlive-backports PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/163683/18533). Before I started I removed all TexLive-related packages. The installation finished and everything seems to work fine. The only thing I noticed are some **warnings** in the output of the installer. Here is an excerpt of the output:

```
Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg
```

There are more of that kind in the rest of the output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive                                                                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  latex-beamer latex-xcolor libgraphite3 libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 lmodern pgf prosper ps2eps tex-common tex-gyre texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common texlive-doc-base texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc
  texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc tipa ttf-marvosym
Suggested packages:
  texlive-doc-en purifyeps chktex latexmk dvipng xindy dvidvi fragmaster lacheck latexdiff t1utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  latex-beamer latex-xcolor libgraphite3 libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 lmodern pgf prosper ps2eps tex-common tex-gyre texlive texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common texlive-doc-base texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc
  texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc tipa ttf-marvosym
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/274 MB of archives.
After this operation, 450 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 

Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package tex-common.
(Reading database ... 290206 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking tex-common (from .../tex-common_3.13~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lmodern.
Unpacking lmodern (from .../lmodern_2.004.1-5~precise1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tex-gyre.
Unpacking tex-gyre (from .../tex-gyre_2.004.1-4~precise1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgraphite3.
Unpacking libgraphite3 (from .../libgraphite3_1%3a2.3.1-0.2build1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkpathsea6.
Unpacking libkpathsea6 (from .../libkpathsea6_2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libptexenc1.
Unpacking libptexenc1 (from .../libptexenc1_2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-common.
Unpacking texlive-common (from .../texlive-common_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-binaries.
Unpacking texlive-binaries (from .../texlive-binaries_2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-doc-base.
Unpacking texlive-doc-base (from .../texlive-doc-base_2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-base.
Unpacking texlive-base (from .../texlive-base_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-latex-base.
Unpacking texlive-latex-base (from .../texlive-latex-base_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-latex-recommended.
Unpacking texlive-latex-recommended (from .../texlive-latex-recommended_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package latex-xcolor.
Unpacking latex-xcolor (from .../latex-xcolor_2.11-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pgf.
Unpacking pgf (from .../archives/pgf_2.10-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package latex-beamer.
Unpacking latex-beamer (from .../latex-beamer_3.10-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-generic-recommended.
Unpacking texlive-generic-recommended (from .../texlive-generic-recommended_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-pstricks.
Unpacking texlive-pstricks (from .../texlive-pstricks_2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package prosper.
Unpacking prosper (from .../prosper_1.00.4+cvs.2007.05.01-4_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ps2eps.
Unpacking ps2eps (from .../ps2eps_1.68-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-marvosym.
Unpacking ttf-marvosym (from .../ttf-marvosym_0.1+dfsg-2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-fonts-recommended.
Unpacking texlive-fonts-recommended (from .../texlive-fonts-recommended_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive.
Unpacking texlive (from .../texlive_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-extra-utils.
Unpacking texlive-extra-utils (from .../texlive-extra-utils_2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-font-utils.
Unpacking texlive-font-utils (from .../texlive-font-utils_2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc.
Unpacking texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (from .../texlive-fonts-recommended-doc_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-latex-base-doc.
Unpacking texlive-latex-base-doc (from .../texlive-latex-base-doc_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-latex-recommended-doc.
Unpacking texlive-latex-recommended-doc (from .../texlive-latex-recommended-doc_2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-pstricks-doc.
Unpacking texlive-pstricks-doc (from .../texlive-pstricks-doc_2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tipa.
Unpacking tipa (from .../tipa_2%3a1.3-17~precise1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 5 added doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Setting up tex-common (3.13~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
texlive-base is not ready, delaying updmap-sys call
texlive-base is not ready, skipping fmtutil-sys --all call
Setting up lmodern (2.004.1-5~precise1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up tex-gyre (2.004.1-4~precise1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up libgraphite3 (1:2.3.1-0.2build1) ...
Setting up libkpathsea6 (2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
Setting up libptexenc1 (2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
Setting up texlive-common (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
Setting up texlive-binaries (2012.20120628-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/xdvi-xaw to provide /usr/bin/xdvi.bin (xdvi.bin) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/bibtex.original to provide /usr/bin/bibtex (bibtex) in auto mode.
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
Building format(s) --refresh.
    This may take some time... done.
Setting up texlive-doc-base (2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up ps2eps (1.68-1) ...
Setting up ttf-marvosym (0.1+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-latex-base-doc (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-latex-recommended-doc (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-pstricks-doc (2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
texlive-base is not ready, delaying updmap-sys call
Setting up texlive-base (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for dvips to a4.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for dvipdfmx to a4.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for xdvi to a4.
/usr/bin/tl-paper: setting paper size for pdftex to a4.


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... done.
Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Setting up texlive-generic-recommended (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-fonts-recommended (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-extra-utils (2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-font-utils (2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-latex-base (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Building format(s) --all --cnffile /etc/texmf/fmt.d/10texlive-latex-base.cnf.
    This may take some time... done.
Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Setting up texlive-pstricks (2012.20120611-1~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up tipa (2:1.3-17~precise1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Setting up texlive-latex-recommended (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Setting up prosper (1.00.4+cvs.2007.05.01-4) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Setting up texlive (2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1) ...
Setting up latex-xcolor (2.11-1) ...
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
Setting up pgf (2.10-1) ...


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Setting up latex-beamer (3.10-1) ...
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

What exactly is `10lmodern.cfg` good for? How can I prevent this warnings?

---

Here is the output of `sudo update-updmap`:

```
$ sudo update-updmap
Regenerating '/var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-DEBIAN'... 

Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg

done.
Regenerating '/var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-TEXLIVEDIST'... done.
update-updmap has updated the following file(s):
    /var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-DEBIAN
    /var/lib/texmf/updmap.cfg-TEXLIVEDIST
If you want to enable the map files with this new file,
you should run updmap-sys or updmap.
```

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look at the [NEWS.Debian file](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/debian-tex/tex-common/trunk/debian/NEWS?revision=5381&view=co). The following is from this file:

> If you are using PostScript fonts that are not packaged for 
>       Debian, some changes have been done: updmap now reads *all*
>       updmap.cfg files it finds. That means, the easiest way to
>       activate local fonts (in `TEXMFLOCAL`) by putting the respective
>       map lines into `/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`, and 
>       call `updmap-sys` once (as root). If you have fonts in your
>       home directory you want to activate, paralleling the above
>       you put the respective map line into `$HOME/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`
>       and call `updmap` (as user). But be reminded that you have to
>       do that everytime system fonts have changed (there is no 
>       automatic syncronization between user specific and system wide
>       `updmap(-sys)` generated files).

In your case it should be sufficient to install the latest version of lmodern, which is 2.004.2-1 for Quantal. After that you run `update-updmap` and the warnung should disappear.

Comment: How can I lookup the version of `lmodern`? When I try to install the package `apt-get` states that my machine is up-to-date. By the way, I am still using Precise not Quantal.

Comment: The command `apt-cache policy lmodern` will show you the version. However if `apt-get` says it is up-to-date, then you have the most recent version.

Comment: Nice. It prompts `Installed: 2.004.1-5~precise1, Candidate: 2.004.1-5~precise1` for me.

Comment: I think i have the same problem. How do install the latest version of lmodern?

Comment: Problem solved for me.