# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: dpkg

I have recently upgrade ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

I am not sure if it works as it should because when I do the command:

sudo apt-get upgrade this happens:

```
kenneth@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for kenneth: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up tex-common (6.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!


Warning: Old configuration style found in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
Warning: For now these files have been included, 
Warning: but expect inconsistencies.
Warning: These packages should be rebuild with tex-common.
Warning: Please see /usr/share/doc/tex-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/00updmap.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10lmodern.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10texlive-base.cfg
Warning: found file: /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10texlive-latex-base.cfg

Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.DDEzsIKu
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base-doc:
 texlive-latex-base-doc depends on tex-common (>= 6); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-latex-base-doc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the problem and how shall I solve it?

---

When i in terminal type in: apt-cache policy lmodern

```
kenneth@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy lmodern
lmodern:
  Installed: 2.004.5-1
  Candidate: 2.004.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.004.5-1 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Is this the newest version of Imodern?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://askubuntu.com/questions/229454/how-to-deal-with-configuration-style-warnings-occuring-from-texlive-2012-install

Comment: No, i try to have i look.

Comment: Does someone knows how I install  the latest version of lmodern? What command?