# How do I add the latex backport PPAs to synaptic in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, ppa, repository, synaptic, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)

I would like to synaptic to have access to the repository files on this website:
http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html

I have tried typing in the web page in the appropriate place, but that does not seem to work.

There is a further problem: When I do the `apt-get install texlive` it goes right to the 2009 version. If I add the 2012 version on the website, does that mean that it wont work with 12.04?