# install koma-script for texworks on ubuntu

Tags: latex, text-editor, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)

I was updating my resume and since I had recently switched to using Ubuntu and Latex I decided I would rewrite it in this environment. I downloaded a template, but when I compiled it (in TexWorks) received the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `scrartcl.cls' not  found.
```

After looking this error up I found it was because a non-standard article class was being used:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{**scrartcl**}
```

scrartcl.cls is from the [Koma-Script project](http://www.komascript.de/), brief description [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). I [downloaded the package](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/koma-script3/), uncompressed it and then added the path in TexWorks: Edit->Preferences->Typesetting.

Unfortunately the above error remains. I read somewhere that you could type "texdoc koma" into the terminal. This produced the message:

```
Sorry, no documentation found for koma.
```

Maybe I need to install it? The install.txt file says:

> Finally, update or 'refresh' the filename database. With teTeX and
>   teTeX-based systems this is done with the program `texconfig' or
>   directly with 'texhash' or 'mktexlsr'.

Not really sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163682)

Comment: After fixing the above problem I found I was still missing other packages (in my case wrapfig.sty).

I think the easiest way to fix these kind of problems (at least for someone like me) is to install the [TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages] (http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist) from the software centre. The TeX Live packages in the software centre solved all my dependency problems.

Hopefully this helps someone else... back to resume writing ;)