# E: Unable to locate package texlive-generic-recommended

Tags: 20.04, texlive

The error message when running the command from the terminal `sudo apt-get install texlive-generic-recommended` is in the subject. [I followed the first answer from this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250850/unable-to-locate-package-texlive), but to no avail.

Comment: That package was dropped after Ubuntu 18.04. It is not available for 20.04.

Comment: Which file-name with filetypes like *.sty*, *.tex*, *.bst* do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The `texlive-generic-recommended` package [was presented in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/texlive-generic-recommended). Its source package is named [`texlive-base`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/texlive-base).

Depending on your needs you can install one of the following package:

- `texlive-fonts-recommended` - TeX Live: Recommended fonts
- `texlive-fonts-recommended-doc` - TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-recommended
- `texlive-latex-recommended` - TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
- `texlive-latex-recommended-doc` - TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-recommended

Note: if you know the name of missed *.sty*, *.tex*, *.bst* files - you can use [packages.ubuntu.com for file-search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=animals.sty).

Comment: Will this also work for Ubuntu 20.04? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but you have not answered the above question. "Which file-name with filetypes like .sty, .tex, .bst do you need exactly?"

Comment: Hello, I think I need .tex