# Why cannot Texmaker find Latex?

Tags: latex

I installed Texlive into `/opt/texlive`. Also I've added the path of Latex to `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc`. Thereafter I installed Texmaker.

I launched Texmaker by searching in Unity dash. But when compiling the `.tex` files, Texmaker fails to find latex.

What should I do?

Comment: Unroll all changes and make it the [right way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012).

Comment: Thanks for your replying. But I really want to keep the current status and to find a way to solve it.

Comment: @m0nhawk: That provides only TL2012, not TL2013.

Comment: _How_ did you install TL?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in **Texmaker**, go to **Options** → **Configure Texmaker** and change the paths for the programs.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I tried. There is blank in "Configure Texmaker" which is marked as "Add to PATH", I add my path "/opt/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux" to the blank space. But Still not work.

Comment: @user200979 That is not the right path. You should insert the executable filename also.

Comment: Do you mean I have to modify "latex" with  /opt/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/latex ?

Comment: @aban The path should be this: `/opt/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/latex`

Comment: Yes, I tried, but still not work for me.

Comment: I solved it now. Thanks any way. My Solution is : add "the path of latex to ~/.profile". It works well now.

Comment: @aban It will work if you remove that path from  Texmaker configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution and share with friends who encountered the similar problems. 
I just add some commands into the ~/.profile file. Here are the command:

```
if [ -d "/opt/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux" ] ; then
  PATH="/opt/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: You don't tell us _how_ you installed TL. But see the section "Post-install: setting PATH" at https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html