# When are the Backports PPA for TexLive back online again?

Tags: latex, backport

In order to do what is suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/163683 the repositories have to actually work but I get a 404 when trying to install from them

When are the Backports PPA for TexLive back online again?

Comment: Can you please **edit** you question and include exact command and the corresponding error.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently running Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring).

The TexLive Backports PPA is intended to be used by Ubuntu 12.04 users as it contains backported TexLive packages from Ubuntu 12.10 to 12.04.

The packages you want can be installed without adding any PPA.

Comment: thanks. however it doesn't solve my initial problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138963/38312 ... but that is not part of this question

Comment: also when installing with apt-get, biblatex will be out of date

Comment: Then you have to download TeXLive from the official website: http://www.tug.org/texlive/