# Why am I getting missing packages in Tex

Tags: texlive

I am trying to install texlive 2012. I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I followed the instructions here: [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)

but I now get error messages such as "ulem.sty not found". What did I do wrong?

Comment: What instructions did you follow, exactly? there are several answers in the question you linked. As far as I can tell, `ulem.sty` is provided by package `texlive-generic-recommended` - perhaps that particular subpackage didn't get picked up as a dependency?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following command sequence:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

This will get you the complete TeXLive package constellation. It is over 1 GB of stuff, but you will never worry with missing packages again. Both `texlive` and `texlive-base` provide only a subset of packages for the economy of space.

Answer (score 17):

The answer from Luís might not be for everyone since it requires to download a lot of packages that you might not need.

`ulem.sty` can actually be found in a much smaller package (3 MiB instead of 1 000 MiB), namely `texlive-generic-recommended`:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-generic-recommended
```

### For Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-plain-generic
```

(as mentioned by rmobis in the comments)

Comment: Wonderful. It worked fine and solved my problem with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: perfect answer, no need to add an extra PPA

Comment: Better answer. Fixed an issue I had rendering markdown to pdf with pandoc; "File `ulem.sty' not found"

Comment: For Ubuntu 20, use `texlive-plain-generic` instead.