# How to install Texlive on Kubuntu 15.04 (tar.gz)

Tags: package-management, 15.04, kubuntu, texlive, muon-package-manager

I hope you can help me. I download TexLive to install it...

I went the manual path. The other also doesn't work. (I want the newest Version of 2015)

I do the stuff like the Ubuntu wiki say, without any success. I try several time stuff an it doesn't work.

I have unzip it with right click mouse technique and try it about the terminal. Now I have on my dolphin desktop an unzip install folder. After the command

```
cd /home/user/install-tl
```

I get `not found` ... I try several times and try often an don't get it.

How should I proceed?

---

thanks for your answer. In the Moment there runs the installation.

I checked the way ... can you give me a hint for the codes/commands? How you get it...? 
I try to expand my talents on Ubuntu and search for the best wiki suff or something like that... or it is only learning by doing.

Is there a very good chart or something with all commands and a pathfinder map or something like that?

Thank a lot

Monkeyhead

Comment: have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)

Comment: please follow my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reinstalling first run the commands,

```
rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2015
rm -rf ~/.texlive2015
```

then,
Download the [.tar.gz](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz)

open terminal and run following commands,

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
```

Currently we have version `20150927`, therefore

```
cd install-tl-20150927
```

and install via

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

You wil see something like this

```
======================> TeX Live installation procedure <=====================

======>   Letters/digits in <angle brackets> indicate   <=======
======>   menu items for commands or options            <=======

 Detected platform: GNU/Linux on Intel x86

 <B> binary platforms: 1 out of 19

 <S> set installation scheme (scheme-full)

 <C> customizing installation collections
     47 collections out of 48, disk space required: 4038 MB

 <D> directories:
   TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
     !! default location: /usr/local/texlive/2015
     !! is not writable or not allowed, please select a different one!
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2015/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2015/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
     ~/texmf

 <O> options:
   [ ] use letter size instead of A4 by default
   [X] allow execution of restricted list of programs via \write18
   [X] create all format files
   [X] install macro/font doc tree
   [X] install macro/font source tree
   [ ] create symlinks to standard directories

 <V> set up for portable installation

Actions:
 <I> start installation to hard disk
 <H> help
 <Q> quit

Enter command:
```

make your changes and type `I` to install.

Comment: Nice answer. Tested, it works =)

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the Moment there runs the installation.

I checked the way ... can you give me a hint for the codes/commands? How you get it...? I try to expand my talents on Ubuntu and search for the best wiki suff or something like that... or it is only learning by doing.

Is there a very good chart or something with all commands and a pathfinder map or something like that?

Thank a lot

Monkeyhead

Comment: If it solved your problem(as you mentioned in question) please accept it...by clicking tick mark at left side of my answer!...As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**
`