# Miktex equivalent for 12.04 (open for more suggestions)

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, latex

I was using MikTeX in Windows 7. Now that I have changed to Ubuntu 12.04, I was looking for a equivalent replacement for it.

I tried [MikTeX](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/install-miktex-a-latex-package-manager-for-ubuntu/) for Debian systems but the following error came:

```
dpkg: error processing /home/venom/Download/miktex-tools-2.8_beta_2-1-i386-linux.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
/home/venom/Download/miktex-tools-2.8_beta_2-1-i386-linux.deb`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead ok miktex that's oriented to windows, you could try Tex Live:

Open terminal and add TeX Live backports ppa via this command:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa

Update the source:

> sudo apt-get update

Now install tex live 2012 with this command:

> sudo apt-get install texlive

There's also some good information you could read on our forum:

[Problems installing TeX Live 2012 on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160676/problems-installing-tex-live-2012-on-12-04)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and choose the answer as the solution

Comment: cant voteup my rep less than 15...
so after you!!! :P

Comment: Why not `texlive` from repos?